# Does a successful Tumble Through trigger reactions?

Tags: reactions, pathfinder-2e

The text of tumble through says:

> You Stride up to your Speed. During this movement, you can try to move through the space of one enemy. Attempt an Acrobatics check against the enemy’s Reflex DC as soon as you try to enter its space. You can Tumble Through using Climb, Fly, Swim, or another action instead of Stride in the appropriate environment.

This doesn't mention that it won't trigger reactions such as attacks of opportunity. However in **Failure** it states:

> Your movement ends, and you trigger reactions as if you had moved out of the square you started in.

Which implies that success won't trigger those reactions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Tumbling triggers as normal if successful

What the additional rule for failing does is that it makes you trigger reactions as if you had left a square you did not actually leave. This is how it goes:

You run up to the fighter and enter his range. No reactions triggered normally. You attempt to Tumble Through. You fail, causing you to not be able to move further with that action. The special rule kicks in and grants a reaction trigger.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes a lot of sense and justifies why it's in the failure state.